# AWS Glue connection failing with self-hosted MongoDB on EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

I'm trying to establish an AWS Glue connection with MongoDB on self-hosted EC2.

- The connection is in the same subnet(private) as MongoDB.
- The connection has same security group as the MongoDB instance, with all the ports open within the same SG.
- No NaCl level blocking either.

Whenever I test the connection, it throws this error
[image]

with cloudwatch logs saying this (No matter what I do it's always this error). PS: I've tested the creds on Mongo Compass, and they work fine:
[image]

But MongoDB logs on the instance tells a different story:

```
2022-08-26T07:18:50.819+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from X.X.X.X:47220 #1684844 (7 connections now open)
2022-08-26T07:18:50.822+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1684844] end connection X.X.X.X:47220 (6 connections now open)
2022-08-26T07:18:51.323+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from X.X.X.X:47222 #1684845 (7 connections now open)
2022-08-26T07:18:51.327+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1684845] end connection X.X.X.X:47222 (6 connections now open)
2022-08-26T07:18:51.562+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from X.X.X.X:47224 #1684846 (7 connections now open)
2022-08-26T07:18:51.562+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1684846] SSL mode is set to 'preferred' and connection 1684846 to X.X.X.X:47224 is not using SSL.
2022-08-26T07:18:51.562+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1684846] received client metadata from X.X.X.X:47224 conn1684846: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.10.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.14.238-125.422.amzn1.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1-b14" }
2022-08-26T07:18:51.584+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from X.X.X.X:47226 #1684847 (8 connections now open)
2022-08-26T07:18:51.585+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1684847] SSL mode is set to 'preferred' and connection 1684847 to X.X.X.X:47226 is not using SSL.
2022-08-26T07:18:51.585+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1684847] received client metadata from X.X.X.X:47226 conn1684847: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.10.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.14.238-125.422.amzn1.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1-b14" }
2022-08-26T07:18:51.615+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn1684847] Successfully authenticated as principal <masked-user> on <masked-db> from client X.X.X.X:47226
2022-08-26T07:18:51.687+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1684847] end connection X.X.X.X:47226 (7 connections now open)
```

The mongodb logs clearly says:
`Successfully authenticated as principal <masked-user> on <masked-db> from client X.X.X.X:47226` still glue keeps failing the connection.

The logs prove that:

- Glue is able to establish connection, meaning SG rules are fine
- The user is authenticated, meaning creds are apt.

Not sure what I'm missing here.
The crawlers are not working since Glue connection keeps failing.
Any help would be really appreciated.